# set environment variable from batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, environment-variables

When I set a environment variable `envir` using `setx` command, It seems to not actually 'set' in environment.

```
setx envir "windows"
if 1==1 (
    setx envir "unix"
)
echo %envir%
set
```

The `set` command displays a list of environment variable but it doesn't display the variable which was currently set by the previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the environment variable `%ENVIR%` is set to `"windows`".
This is stored in the user-specific environment variables in the `Windows` registry. The change is not directly reflected in the environments of currently active processes.

To actually see this new setting via `set` command, you have to open a new command box using `cmd.exe`. The current command box does not automatically re-read changed settings from the registry. You could also use the system control `SYSTEM` and look under `Extended Properties / Environment`:

[image]

Comment: or  after running `setx aaa 3`, run `set aaa=3` to set it in the current cmd prompt.  Also, setx can be a bit dangerous, it's worth doing `set>a.a` first so if setx does write something a way you didn't intend, then you have a backup

Answer (score 0):

Axel is correct.

`setx` stores the variable in the registry, but the change is not reflected in the environment of ANY running program (including the current one).

Here are some relevant parts of the output of `setx /?`:

```
C:\>setx /?

Description:
    Creates or modifies environment variables in the user or system
    environment. Can set variables based on arguments, regkeys or
    file input.

NOTE: 1) SETX writes variables to the master environment in the registry.

      2) On a local system, variables created or modified by this tool
         will be available in future command windows but not in the
         current CMD.exe command window.

      3) On a remote system, variables created or modified by this tool
         will be available at the next logon session.
```